# Geometric Notation

Tags: notation

What is does the curve on top of EB in the picture mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chord maybe? Just a guess.

Comment: Perhaps if you include the whole image (the surrounding context) it would be easier to know.

Comment: I'd say *arc*...

Comment: Yeah, my best guess is the arclength from E to B.

Comment: It's the measure of the central angle (in this case, in degrees) associated with that arc. But be careful, there are two possible arcs, so you need more context to tell which. The sum of the degree measures of the two arcs is always equal to $360^\circ$.

Comment: Here is the picture in the answer section:

Comment: I may be wrong, but in the equation image, I think that the "-" should be "=".